# TypeScript equivalent of Array.from()

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dom

Is there an `Array.from()` equivalent in **TypeScript**?
Or, is there a way to use the `Array.from()` implementation that is found in browsers?

I'm trying to convert a NodeList into an array in order to use array methods.
This is what I would do with vanilla JavaScript:

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
const arrDivs = Array.from(divs);
const result = arrDivs.map(e => {...});
```

<strike>`Array.from()` is not available in TypeScript, it has it's own `Array` implementation.</strike>

So I think I would have to cast it to an `Element[]` or a `HTMLElement[]` like this:

```
const arrDivs = <HTMLElement[]>divs;
```

But then I get the following error:

> Conversion of type 'NodeListOf' to type 'HTMLElement[]' may
>   be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the
>   other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown'
>   first.   Type 'NodeListOf' is missing the following
>   properties from type 'HTMLElement[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 14
>   more.

So then I instead have to first cast the NodeList to an `unknown` and then to the `HTMLElement[]`:

```
const arrDivs = <HTMLElement[]><unknown>divs;
```

This seems to disregard the inherent type safety of TypeScript. So I'm wondering if there's a better or more correct way to do this? Or some way to call the native `Array.from()` function found in modern browsers?

**UPDATE**
My compiler is telling me that `Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'.`

Here are my compiler options:

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    // Linting rules:
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
}
```

Comment: All javascript is available from typescript, not the other way around

Comment: `Array.from() is not available in TypeScript, it has it's own Array implementation.`, no, TypeScript doesn't implement anything, it just provides type support for JavaScript. If you can do something in JavaScript, you can do it also in TypeScript - in a safer and better environment

Comment: `Array.from()` [exists](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgSwG4RgXniYBXAtgUzCgDoBHbfAJwE8BlfAG32ChEoEEGGAKAckSS8AlAG4AsAChQkWAENKlACLJUGdgtnViAM0ohc3ARFGTp0GJXwRsDWBnlKVxXLIAO3fOgB8MfMQRgYFQAKvgAHlAmEkA)

Comment: What are your compiler options?

Comment: You should be able to use `[...divs].map(...)`. Might also be missing some compiler options.

Comment: I'm getting `Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'.` when I try to compile. So then maybe I've got something wrong in my compiler options? Will post them in a question update.

Comment: For those looking for syntax: `const arr = Array.from<type>(iterable);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are targeting ES2015 or upwards in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es2015"
}
```

When you omit that field, [it defaults to `"es3"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#target) which is a JS version that `Array.from` is not a thing.

Comment: That makes sense. I would actually prefer to keep it to ES3 because this code will be running on TV browsers, and some of them are running very old JS interpreters.

Comment: If that's your target, then I'd use combination of babel and typescript via webpack. I'd target `es2020` in typescript and instruct `babel-loader` to provide polyfills on the fly and lower the codebase to whatever is need to support the browsers that I listed to target in `.browserslistrc`.

Comment: Ended up targeting ES5 and just using a for loop to loop over the HTML collection.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Use `//@ts-ignore` above Array.from(divs) line.

Run code.